# ejecutar canvas dinamicamente con un boton

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy creando canvas dinamicamente con input, para este ejemplo puse 2 canvas con el mismo id. lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que al llamar el canvas con el boton se me genere el dibujo. de igual manera si al presionar el segundo boton que entre y me genere el mismo dibujo.

Codigo:

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
var a_canvas = document.getElementById("a");
var context = a_canvas.getContext("2d");

$('#draw').click(function() {
// Draw the face
context.fillStyle = "yellow";
context.beginPath();
context.arc(95, 85, 40, 0, 2*Math.PI);
context.closePath();
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.stroke();
context.fillStyle = "black";

// Draw the left eye
context.beginPath();
context.arc(75, 75, 5, 0, 2*Math.PI);
context.closePath();
context.fill();

// Draw the right eye
context.beginPath();
context.arc(114, 75, 5, 0, 2*Math.PI);
context.closePath();
context.fill();

// Draw the mouth
context.beginPath();
context.arc(95, 90, 26, Math.PI, 2*Math.PI, true);
context.closePath();
context.fill();

// Write "Hello, World!"
context.font = "30px Garamond";
context.fillText("Hello, World!",15,175);
});
});
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas class="u" id="a" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<div>
<button id="draw">Draw</button>
      </div>
      
<canvas id="a" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<div>
<button id="draw">Draw</button>
</div>
```

una de la forma que estoy tratando de hacer es que en `var a_canvas = document.getElementById("a");` o por la clase

Comment: Hola Eduard, bienvenido. En HTML no debe haber dos elementos con el mismo  `ID`.

Comment: Listo, entonces genero el id dinamicamente, pero como hago para llamarlo desde var a_canvas = document.getElementById("a");

Comment: Y no puedes crear un button con diferentes id y que cada uno cuando se le de clic actualice el canvas al que hace referencia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes usar el mismo ID dos veces y esperar que javascript o jQuery adivinen cual es cual.

En el siguiente ejemplo implementé lo que propones usando clases. Ahora, ambos botones tienen la misma clase `draw`, pero además tienen el atributo `rel` que les permite saber a qué canvas deben apuntar.

```js
$(document).ready(function (){


$('.draw').click(function() {

var a_canvas =document.getElementById( jQuery(this).attr('rel'));
var context = a_canvas.getContext("2d");

// Draw the face
context.fillStyle = "yellow";
context.beginPath();
context.arc(95, 85, 40, 0, 2*Math.PI);
context.closePath();
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.stroke();
context.fillStyle = "black";

// Draw the left eye
context.beginPath();
context.arc(75, 75, 5, 0, 2*Math.PI);
context.closePath();
context.fill();

// Draw the right eye
context.beginPath();
context.arc(114, 75, 5, 0, 2*Math.PI);
context.closePath();
context.fill();

// Draw the mouth
context.beginPath();
context.arc(95, 90, 26, Math.PI, 2*Math.PI, true);
context.closePath();
context.fill();

// Write "Hello, World!"
context.font = "30px Garamond";
context.fillText("Hello, World!",15,175);
});
});
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="float:left;">
  <canvas class="u" id="canvas1" width="200" height="200"></canvas><br>
  <button class="draw" rel="canvas1">Draw</button>
</div>
      

<div style="float:left;">
<canvas id="canvas2" width="200" height="200"></canvas><br>
<button class="draw" rel="canvas2">Draw</button>
</div>
```

Hay otras maneras de hacer esto mismo, incluso sin ayudarse con el atributo `rel`. Por ejemplo, podrías hacer que el botón apunte al primer canvas hijo de su parent element, pero el detalle de la implementación escapa al alcance de esta respuesta.